# AJAX JSON response doesn't refresh for tag at Django template

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I have built a view in views.py that returns a JSON when user press a button. The page updates simple html divs (last_bid, credits, message) without reloading but I have some {% for %} tags that don't refresh although JSON response is updated with extra data.

template.html script

```
<script>
$('#bid').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{% some url %}',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
            some data
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#last-bid').html(data.last_bid);
            $('#credits').html(data.credits);
            $('#message').html(data.message);
            $('#registered_players').html(data.registered_players);              
        }
    });
});
```

template.html

```
<div id="registered_players">
{% for i in registered_players %}
    {{ i.auction_player__user__username }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

JSON

```
{"registered_players": [{"auction_player__user__username": "admin"}, {"auction_player__user__username": "minos"}], "last_bid": "8.10", "credits": 612, "message": ""}
```

Comment: Django specific tags cannot work on front-end. They only work on back-end. If you want to render json to html on front-end (ajax) you need some JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting the div "registered_players". Either you need to loop through your JSON data and replace every single player Or you need to remove the old players html and add your new HTML.
Please provide your HTML by inspecting the html page for more clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. Managed to solve this by looping through JSON response.

```
var player_list = "<ul>";
            for (var i=0; i< data.registered_players.length; i++){ 
               player_list += "<li>" + data.registered_players[i].auction_player__user__username + "</li>";
             }
            player_list += "</ul>"                
            $('#registered_players').html(player_list);
```